# What does it mean when the discriminator's loss gets a constant value while the generator's loss keeps on changing?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-networks

While training a GAN-based model, every time the discriminator's loss gets a constant value of nearly 0.63 while the generator's loss keeps on changing from 0.5 to 1.5, so I am not able to understand if this thing is happening either due to the generator being successful in fooling the discriminator or some instability in training. I have been stuck in this confusion for so many days.